# PHP Form sends to email form data in email header

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a form here that when submitted, it gets sent to my email. Is there a way that when it sends, it can be FROM a specific value in one of the fields (it'll be a field that asks for their email address). This is just so that it's easier to reply to their message. Right now it's sending to my email address as my $where_form_is.

```
<?php

$where_form_is="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].strrev(strstr(strrev($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),"/"));

$from = $_REQUEST['field_1'];

mail("email@gmail.com"," Application ","Application Data:

Email (so we can reply):
" . $_POST['field_1'] . " 

In Game Name:
" . $_POST['field_2'] . " 

Please name ALL characters that you still actively play:
" . $_POST['field_3'] . " 

Name/Nickname you prefer to be called:
" . $_POST['field_4'] . " 

Age:
" . $_POST['field_5'] . " 

Country/Time zone:
" . $_POST['field_6'] . " 

How often do you play?:
" . $_POST['field_7'] . " 

Which Boss Runs are you familiar with?:
" . $_POST['field_8'] . "

Previous guilds and reason for leaving/kick:
" . $_POST['field_9'] . " 

Why do you want to join?:
" . $_POST['field_10'] . " 

How did you find out about us?:
" . $_POST['field_11'] . " 

Do you know anyone from here? If so, who?:
" . $_POST['field_12'] . " 

Referrals (2-3 Contact IGNs of Previous Guild Masters/Junior Masters):
" . $_POST['field_13'] . " 

Best way to contact you?:
" . $_POST['field_14'] . " 

Any additional comments?:
" . $_POST['field_15'] . " 

", "$from"
);

include("confirm.html");

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mail` has a fourth parameter: `header`, here's an example:

```
$header = "From: ". $Name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n"; //optional headerfields
mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header);
```

from over [here](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php), which can be adopted to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, just replace your e-mail with that value like that the other values.

```
 $email = $_POST['email'];

 mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: that would send the mail back to the one filling in the form ??? Not what the OP wants, he wants to receive the mail with the sender address from the form in order to reply to it more easily.

Comment: @AxelAmthor the way she wrote sounds like my solution. I shouldn't get negative for it.